# Find out YouTubeUserID if I know display name

Tags: c#, youtube-api

How to get YouTubeUserID if I know YouTube display name alone with API V2 & C#?
I have tried

```
string userDetailsUrl = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}?alt=json";
string youtubeurl = String.Format(userDetailsUrl, formValues["[0].UserFullName"].Trim().Replace(" ", ""));
```

Here in UserFullName I was giving the display name. But its not giving me exact result in all the cases. so please suggest any alternate way.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't use V3 yet, you should at least be using v2.1, so make your call to:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{0}?alt=json&v=2.1
```

Then there will be, in the response, a lot of extra attributes returned in the payload entries, one of which will be:

```
author.yt$userId
```

And finally, if you can't use v 2.1, then take the response from the gdata request you noted above, and look at the id attribute ... it'll have a value something like this:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw
```

Take the last fragment of the URL, append the letters 'UC' before the underscore, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have already know which element will contain YT userid. My problem is What I will pass as parameter( for 'users/{0}' ) since I know only User's DISPLAY NAME (which is not unique); not unique User name.

Comment: My apologies ... I thought you wanted to get the userid from the display name. If you have the userID, just pass that instead of the full name or the display name, and it should work as well; they were designed to be interchangable to allow people to move away from display names (for the very reason you mention ... they aren't unique).

Comment: thanks jlmcdonald. I think you got confused with my comment. I know only the user's display name for eg: Pls search for 'Sridhar Narayanan' in youtube. You can see some  5 to 6 profiles with same name. My question is if I know 'Sridhar Narayanan' ie, Display name of the user; how I will find our unique userid ?

Comment: So, if all you know is the display name, you'll have to make a GET request to https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{DISPLAY_NAME_HERE}?alt=json&v=2.1 ... and if there are multiple users, you'll have to  loop through the results and apply some sort of logic to figure out which one you really want. It would be illogical to say you want a way to get the unique user ID among many non-unique display names, because YouTube can't just guess which one you really want. Where do you get the displayName from originally? Maybe that source can give you something else to match on?

Comment: this GET wont work it will tell like page not found. Actually i have an application in which we will fetch the YT videos with particular Key words. And we will display Video, Display name of the person who uploaded the video , comments etc. There is another functionality to filter out some of the users from this for that we have a data entry screen there we were trying to save display name. What I have done is since Display name is not unique I tried a GET call for unique user id & save in Database. So that I can filter out by comparing Author ID of video with the Unique user id saved in DB

Comment: Could you give an example of the actual call to get the json data?